# Triple-booting Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot

I'm currently dual-booting Windows 7 and 8 (Consumer Preview). If I install Ubuntu, will I be able to switch between all three operating systems?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do so - grub will recognise and add them to the boot list for you.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu install will break windows 8 so back up boot files (with 7 the first two files are usually in a separate 100MB boot partition)
/bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe 
You could make up a recovery disc from within (both)windows before trying to install ubuntu (this will save you uninstalling ubuntu and windows 8 in order to reinstall/repair windows 8)

This thread here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1955926 could help to understand what happens and how to fix or prevent some of the issues that are preventing windows being unhappy sharing a machine with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ans is YES

for doing this

1 -  make sure it will not go beyond the 4 primary parition if it so then your pc will not boot up

2 - you can make extra partion by gparted tool but it will not more than 4 in case of primary partition while other extented parition is allowed

3 - after having the sufficient space for windows 8 then

4 - install windows 8

5 - now you notice that only windows 7 and 8 is listed in windows boot loader

6 - now you have 2 option

```
1 - add ubuntu in windows boot loader by using easyBCD (http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

2 - reinstall grub 2 by live cd 

    for this watch video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I

    after this if your windows in not listed in grub 2 then type 
    "sudo update-grub2"
    even if the windows is not listed retry after mounting your windows drive 

    here is the video for updating grub2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJDcyAncmRY
```